# I need a procedure for unify multiple insert

Tags: mysql, wordpress, insert, procedure

I'm new to mysql. I need to unify these 2 insert to make my work faster, but I don't know well sql programming.

First I have to populate wp_terms, than the wp_term_taxonomy using the term_id as key.

This one create a row with term_id (field term_id not present, is a AUTOINCREMENT one) = 1

```
INSERT INTO wp_terms(name, slug, term_group) 
VALUES ('Pippo','pippo'0)
```

So, to make relationship between two tables I used this one:

```
INSERT INTO wp_term_taxonomy (term_id,taxonomy,parent)
SELECT wp_terms.term_id,'category','1' FROM wp_terms WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id);
```

How can I run above insert at the same time?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, if I get your goal correct. Is the following what you want to do?
Insert s.th. to wp_terms, get the autoinc value back and use it for an insert to wp_term_taxonomy?

Comment: Hi. I've to insert a parent-child category (wp_terms e wp_term_traxonomy are related). The firs insert has many rows and create a progressive term_id that i've to insert into secondo table (wp_term_taxonomy).

Answer (score 0):

You can use "trigger after insert".
Here there is a tutorial http://www.roseindia.net/sql/trigger/mysql-trigger-after-insert.shtml

Comment: I like this solution, but i've to change the second insert to perform a different one.